# See what data is left to decode through Decoder

Tags: swift, codable

I'm working in a Swiftt 4 project where Codable is utilized. However, I'm getting the following error:

```
No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: "postable_type", intValue: nil) ("postable_type").
```

Now what I'm wondering is how to best debug this. Is there a possibility to see what data Codable is trying to cram in my model? Especially because the one in this case makes use of fairly advanced nesting, I recon it'd be a real lifesaver here...

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

`Codable` errors are very descriptive. For debugging use this `catch` block to get detailed error messages:

```
} catch DecodingError.dataCorrupted(let context) {
    print(context)
} catch DecodingError.keyNotFound(let key, let context) {
    print("Key '\(key)' not found:", context.debugDescription)
    print("codingPath:", context.codingPath)
} catch DecodingError.valueNotFound(let value, let context) {
    print("Value '\(value)' not found:", context.debugDescription)
    print("codingPath:", context.codingPath)
} catch DecodingError.typeMismatch(let type, let context)  {
    print("Type '\(type)' mismatch:", context.debugDescription)
    print("codingPath:", context.codingPath)
} catch {
    print("error: ", error)
}
```

Both `debugDescription` and `codingPath` tells you exactly what is wrong and where.

Comment: Note that if all associated values are constants you can also  write it as: `catch let DecodingError.typeMismatch(type, context)`